# Targeting Classes in Table Row

Tags: javascript, html-table

The code:

```
var table = document.getElementById('some-table');
var row = table.rows;

alert(row.length); // Returns number of rows

// Function to hide class on specific row when some action is performed
function someFunc(i) {
    var elementToTarget = row[i].getElementsByClassName('some-class');
    var otherElementToTarget = row[i].getElementsByClassName('some-other-class');

    elementToTarget.style.display="none"; // Returns "elementToTarget.style
                                          //          is undefined"
    otherElementToTarget.style.display="inline"; // Returns undefined
}
```

Basic table layout:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="some-class"></div>
            <div class="some-other-class"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**What I want to do:** When a user triggers someFunc(), it hides some-class and displays some-other-class.  But it only hides some-class for that particular row.  Not all of the rows.

**My Problem:** It tells me that the elements in that row are undefined and I cannot perform any actions on them.  It's very likely that I'm targetting those classes improperly.

Hopefully, I've been clear enough.  If you need more clarification let me know.

**Edit:** There may not always be 'some-other-class' in the row.  That's why I can't just target one of the divs.  I need to know their row.

Comment: Where is `someFunc()` called and with what parameter?

Comment: @RGraham In this example it would be on the some-other-class div.  Like so, onclick=someFunc(0) (since its the first row).  But if it were on the 53rd row it would be someFunc(52).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refer you to the getElementsByClassName function's API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

Also, notice the name - Element***s***. It returns a list. And your function should treat it accordingly. so, e.g:

```
var elementToTarget = row[i].getElementsByClassName('some-class')[0];
var otherElementToTarget = row[i].getElementsByClassName('some-other-class')[0];
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YD78S/